# How to wait for $.getJSON()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this problem where I do an .each() on this group of selects, for each one it fires off a call to the server for some data to populate it with. However I couldn't figure out why it would only populate the bottomest one. Then I threw in some alerts() and realized it was only running the call back function on the last one multiple times. I realized that by the time the first JSON call was done, $(this) was something different... How can I get it to wait so all of them will be populated by the proper call?

HERE IS THE SCRIPT PART:

```
var thisbundle;
var testcount = 0;

//get bundle options first..
$("select.bundle").each(function() {

  thisbundle = $(this);
  testcount++;
  var url = "/order/getpricing/" + thisbundle.attr("id");

  //clear it out...
  //thisbundle.children().remove();

  var passbundle = thisbundle;
  $.getJSON(url, function(data, passbundle) {
    var options = '';
    for (n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
      options += '<option value="' + data[n].volumeID + '">' + explainPricing(data, n) + '</option>';

    }
    passbundle.html(options);
  });
});
```

AND HERE IS THE FORM PART:

```
<div id="bundles">
<table>
    <%foreach (KODmvc.Models.Product prod in Model.products)
      {%>
            <%if (prod.NumberOfCourses > 1)
              { %>
                <tr><td><img src="<%=prod.Icon %>" /></td><td><b><%=prod.Title%></b><br /><%=prod.Description%></td><td><select class="bundle" id="<%=prod.ProductID %>"><option value="-1">None</option>"</select></td></tr>
            <%} %>
    <%} %>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show some code so we can answer. In general, though, you solve this kind of problem by capturing the value you want in a local variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `thisbundle` in your function and not in the global scope:

```
$("select.bundle").each(function(){
    var thisbundle = $(this);
    // …
});
```

Otherwise the global object would be overwritten with each iteration that the callback function would then use.

Comment: +1. Why didn't I think of this! My answer is overly complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the ajax call in an anonymous function like this. This creates a new closure for every select element. Each of these closures will remember it's own value for `passbundle`.

```
$("select.bundle").each(function(){
    thisbundle = $(this);
    testcount++;
    var url = "/order/getpricing/" + thisbundle.val();
    alert(thisbundle.id);

    //clear it out...
    //thisbundle.children().remove();

    (function(){
        var passbundle = thisbundle;
        $.getJSON(url, function(data, passbundle){
            var options = '';
            for(n = 0; n < data.length; n++){
                options += '<option value="' + data[n].volumeID + '">' + explainPricing(data, n) + '</option>';
            }
            passbundle.html(options);
        });
    })();

});
```

Comment: what if I stopped using passbundle could I still use thisbundle?

Comment: it won't work then. You see the value of thisbundle changes every time the outer loop is run. Your inner functions carry a 'live' pointer to this variable due to the scope. By the time your event handler runs, the value of `thisbundle` variable would be the last value it had.

Comment: but I noticed that passbundle wasn't working right, saying it had no .html, I think it's because $(this) became a JSON call once inside?

Comment: Gumbo's answer has the right effect in creating a local scope. Declaring thisbundle inside function will make copies. It solves your problem in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use async : false, although that might be the wrong direction to head if you are looping.  But it is worth looking at.